# Starting a timer after an application enters onPause?

Tags: java, android

How would I got about implementing a function that starts a 10 second timer countdown when a user switches app and the if the user switches back AFTER the countdown ends, return some logic so the application know the user has exceed the timer? Is there a way to differentiate switching app with turning off the phone screen?

I.e. what do i need do in Android to implement the following?

1. User run apps
2. User switches out of application
3. App checks if its a) a task switch or b) a phone lock.
4. If its a), start a timer.
5. If timer ends, set some logic.
6. User returns to application. App displays a message based on logic in 5.

Comment: Probably could be done using background services?